# Django - Admin forms data generation with fields which are not in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a specific scenario and I am unable to figure out how to approach this problem, some direction will be great help:

I have a model:

```
class RollNumber(models.Model):
    r_no_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Roll number 
                                      suffix')
    r_no= models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Number')
    r_no_suffix = models.CharField(max_length=10,  verbose_name='Roll number 
                                        prefix')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s -%s-%s' % (self.r_no_prefix,self.r_no,self.r_no_suffix)
```

No, I want to generate these Roll numbers in bulk by asking the user to input the following in a form which is not having any of the above model fields.

```
Number of roll numbers you want to generate: ____________
Roll number prefix: ________________
Roll number suffix: ________________

[SUBMIT][CANCEL]
```

1. The submission of above form should be able to generate the number of rollnumbers and create records in RollNumber table in bulk.
2. If I try to use this form again, if should get the last number and then start the sequence from there. Considering the that user may have deleted some of the roll number records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a model form, use a simple form and create the objects in a loop. Something like this:

```
from django import forms
from models import RollNumber

class RollForm(forms.Form):
    times_to_roll = forms.IntegerField()
    prefix = forms.IntegerField()
    suffix = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        rolls = RollNumber.objects.all()
        if not rolls.exists():
            return
        last_roll = rolls.order_by('pk')[-1]
        self.fields['prefix'].initial = last_roll.prefix
        self.fields['suffix'].initial = last_roll.suffix

    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not super(RollForm, self).is_valid(*args, **kwargs):
           return False
       for x in range(self.cleaned_data.times_to_roll):
           RollNumber.objects.create(...)
       return True
```